# smartctl -a /dev/sda shows errors on brand new SSD

Tags: ssd, smartctl

I have just installed brand new SSD into my laptop, and I see `smartctl -a /dev/sda` is showing errors already

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   095   095   050    Old_age   Always       -       2/4698640
  5 Retired_Block_Count     0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours_and_Msec 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0h+16m+22.260s
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0030   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2
177 Wear_Range_Delta        0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
181 Program_Fail_Count      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   037   043   000    Old_age   Always       -       37 (Min/Max 24/43)
195 ECC_Uncorr_Error_Count  0x001c   099   099   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2/4698640
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
201 Unc_Soft_Read_Err_Rate  0x001c   099   099   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2/4698640
204 Soft_ECC_Correct_Rate   0x001c   099   099   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2/4698640
230 Life_Curve_Status       0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       25769803776
233 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
234 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
241 Lifetime_Writes_GiB     0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
242 Lifetime_Reads_GiB      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
```

Specifically, these attributes show non-zero:

```
Raw_Read_Error_Rate
ECC_Uncorr_Error_Count
Unc_Soft_Read_Err_Rate
Soft_ECC_Correct_Rate
```

Does it mean my SSD is already failing ?

Comment: Please: a) Run `sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer` b) Add that plus the make and model of the SSD into your question by clicking [edit]. Please don't do Add Comment, just click [edit] and enhance the question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SMART](https://www.z-a-recovery.com/manual/smart.aspx) values with the TYPE=Pre-fail or FLAG=13h or 33h are what to watch out for. None of those values you are concerned with are in those categories. [Backblaze reports](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2846009/the-5-smart-stats-that-actually-predict-hard-drive-failure.html) item 187, "Reported Uncorrect/Reported_Uncorrectible_Errors" shows as 0, which is good. Here's a more thorough article on the subject of [using smartctl to monitor SSD health](https://linuxhandbook.com/check-ssd-health/).

But, worried about your system? Get another SSD of about the same capacity (an [M.2](https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/M2-SSD), [mSATA](https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/mSATA-SSD-mSATA-solid-state-drive) or [mounted in a DVD replacement carrier](https://www.newmodeus.com/shop/index.php?main_page=page&id=50) in a laptop) and configure [RAID 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_1), because as the article on [smartctl](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Smartctl) noted, 32% of SSD failures occur with no warning from SMART.

M.2 will deliver the same speed in general as an SSD in the SSD bay; using an mSATA or putting a 2.5" drive in a DVD replacement carrier limits you to SATA2.